# How to use AWK to get value between specific time period

Tags: awk

How to get AWK results with specific time interval
I am trying to get number of records which has value more than 950, I am able to do that using ->

```
awk -F'[|=]' '$4>960' file
```

But, i would like to get this value for which logDurationMillis is greater than 950 and also between Specific time periods like 8 pm to 10 pm and 12 am to 8 pm + 10 pm to 12 am

Does AWK/GAWK have functionality to do so ?

```
logAlias=Overall|logDurationMillis=34|logTimeStart=2019-09-12_05:22:02.602|logTimeStop=2019-09-12_05:22:02.636|logTraceUID=43adbcaf55de|getMethod1=26|getMethod2=0|getMethod3=0|getMethod4=1|getMethod5=8
logAlias=Overall|logDurationMillis=975|logTimeStart=2019-09-12_21:22:02.602|logTimeStop=2019-09-12_05:22:02.636|logTraceUID=43adbcaf55de|getMethod1=26|getMethod2=0|getMethod3=0|getMethod4=1|getMethod5=8
logAlias=Overall|logDurationMillis=1267|logTimeStart=2019-09-12_21:47:02.602|logTimeStop=2019-09-12_05:22:02.636|logTraceUID=43adbcaf55de|getMethod1=26|getMethod2=0|getMethod3=0|getMethod4=1|getMethod5=8
logAlias=Overall|logDurationMillis=1654|logTimeStart=2019-09-12_16:22:02.602|logTimeStop=2019-09-12_05:22:02.636|logTraceUID=43adbcaf55de|getMethod1=26|getMethod2=0|getMethod3=0|getMethod4=1|getMethod5=8
logAlias=Overall|logDurationMillis=3874|logTimeStart=2019-09-12_17:22:02.602|logTimeStop=2019-09-12_05:22:02.636|logTraceUID=43adbcaf55de|getMethod1=26|getMethod2=0|getMethod3=0|getMethod4=1|getMethod5=8
logAlias=Overall|logDurationMillis=34|logTimeStart=2019-09-12_21:44:02.602|logTimeStop=2019-09-12_05:22:02.636|logTraceUID=43adbcaf55de|getMethod1=26|getMethod2=0|getMethod3=0|getMethod4=1|getMethod5=8
logAlias=Overall|logDurationMillis=34|logTimeStart=2019-09-12_14:22:02.602|logTimeStop=2019-09-12_05:22:02.636|logTraceUID=43adbcaf55de|getMethod1=26|getMethod2=0|getMethod3=0|getMethod4=1|getMethod5=8
```

I would like to get records for which `logDurationMillis` is greater than 950 and `logTimeStart` between Specific time periods like 8 pm to 10 pm and 12 am to 8 pm + 10 pm to 12 am

Comment: please edit your Q to describe what is the purpose of the `logAlias=...` line. Is that sample data? If so, please show the required output from that data. If not, then your Q does need to include a small set of sample data to test with AND the required output from that same data. Good luck.

Comment: Use the `{}` tool from the Edit menu on mouse-selected text to get the correct formatting for code/data/ErrMsgs. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks Shelter. logAlias does not have any significance apart from mentioning it is the first field in the logs.
Yes, it is a sample data, 
Required output: I want to get all the fields between the given time frame which are mentioned above
Timeframe 1 : 12 AM to 8 PM + 10 PM to 12 AM
Timeframe 2: 8 PM to 10 PM

Comment: @user3512605, could you please add more lines of sample Input and expected sample output in your post itself also wrap them in CODE TAGS too and let us know since your requirement is not clear.

Comment: @user3512605, Please post expected output too in your post.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is to work in the following generic way:

- fields are separated by a single `|`
- each field is a key-value pair which is written as `key=value`
- extract all key-value pairs and store them in an array `a[key]=value`
- extract the information with any combination you like

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS="[|]"}
       { delete a }
       { for(i=1;i<=NF;++i) { split($i,b,"="); key=b[1]; value=b[2]; a[key]=value} }
       { time=a["logTimeStart"];sub(/.*_/,"",time) }
       (a["logDurationMillis"] > 960) && ("20:00:00.000" <= time && time < "22:00:00.000")' file
```

**note:** The OP requests  8 pm to 10 pm and 12 am to 8 pm + 10 pm to 12 am, that is actually a full day. Hence, I give the example to extract 8 pm till 10 pm